# List of all Objective-C preprocessor directives in Clang

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, c-preprocessor

Is there some list of all Objective-C preprocessor directives in Clang? I'm talking about `#pragma mark - Section I` or `#pragma unused (variableName)` or `#warning - message`.

I would like to know more of them to improve my code, but Googling "llvm preprocessor directives" gave me this link: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html, which does not list all the directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of them have not been introduced in LLVM/Clang, but were inherited from GCC. Therefore, searching for `gcc preprocessor directives` may lead to better results. The following document could give you some hints, but it does not seem to be complete (missing some of the above mentioned pragmas) nor is it specific to Objective-C:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html#Top

This index may be faster to browse:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Index-of-Directives.html#Index-of-Directives

Answer (score 1):

**Interfaces & Implementation**

```
@interface...@end
@implementation...@end
@class
```

**Instance Variable Visibility**

```
@public
@package
@protected
@private
```

**Properties**

```
@property
@synthesize
@dynamic
```

**Protocols**

```
@protocol
@required
@optional
```

**Exception Handling**

```
@try
@catch
@finally
@throw
```

**Object Literals**

```
@""
@42, @3.14, @YES, @'Z'
@[]
@{}
@()
```

**Objective-C Literals**

```
@selector()
@protocol()
```

**C Literals**

```
@encode()
@defs()
```

**Optimizations**

```
@autoreleasepool{}
@synchronized{}
```

**Compatibility**

```
@compatibility_alias
```

***Taken from the following link which has an exhaustive list of directives with descriptions: [NSHipster - @ Compiler Directives](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/).***

Comment: None of these are preprocessor directives.