# How to strip single-line comments in obj-c properly

Tags: objective-c, regex

I know there are a lot of resources with regex for it. But I could not find the one I want.
My problem is:
I want to remove one line comments (`//`) from obj-c sources, but I don't want to break the code in it. For instance, with this regex: `@"//.*"` I can remove all comments, but it also corrupts string literal:

```
@"bsdv//sdfsdf"
```

I played with non-capturing parentheses `(?:(\"*\")*+)`, but without success.
Also I found this expression for Python:

`r'(\".*?\"|\'.*?\')|(/\*.*?\*/|//[^\r\n]*$)'`

It should cover my case, but I've not figure out how to make it work with obj-c.

Please, help me to build proper regex.

**UPDATE:** Yeah, that's a tough one, I know there're a lot of caveats, other than the one I described. I would appreciate if someone post regex that only fix my issue. Anyway, I gonna post my solution, without regex soon, I hope it will be helpful for anyone who struggling with such problem too.

Comment: This is going to be hard to do. You need to account for C string literals containing // and although the single line comment applies to the remaining portion of a line before the new line character, your preceding @" or " might be on another line above and a subsequent " respectively might also be on a separate line if the C line continuation character \ is in there followed by a newline. (sometimes found by those who are old school or who hate having to scroll to the right and haven't yet discovered that Xcode will wrap long lines for you. Objective-C has all rules of C. It is a superset.

Comment: You'll also need to handle wacky things like ///* and multi line comments in general. You might take a look at some of the fancy stuff TextMate does for its Objective-C grammar in in the Objective-C bundle, those are great regexes but not bullet-proof. You'll be better off learning to use libclang.

Comment: Basically, you're not likely going to pull this off in a one-liner.

Comment: I just don't believe that no one is made it before me

Comment: Lots have tried, and many come close, but without an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) of some form, it will likely fail in some cases. TextMate has what appear to be simple regexes for this in its Objective-C grammar (on github) but you'll notice, the language grammars are sets of regexes, because they too build something of an AST. I'm not saying don't try, but it's not going to be any easier than developing a syntax highlighting engine.

Comment: Thank you, I've decided to do that with looping through string manually, char by char, and make this check in obj-c code.
Anyway if someone have and post an solution on regex, it will definitely helps not only me but many other peoples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:^|.*;(?!.*")|#(?:define|endif|ifn?def|import|undef|...).*)\s*(//[^\r\n]+$)
```

**Demo**

http://regex101.com/r/jT4xC8

**Description**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Discussion**

Besides all the warnings expressed in the comments, I assume that a single line can appear in two distinct cases:

- **Case 1:** Alone on its line preceded or not by blank chars
- **Case 2:** Not Alone on its line preceded or not by blank chars, and other chars.

In the first case, we match the beginning of the line (`^` with `/m` flag). Then we search  zero or more blank chars (`\s*`) and finally the single line comment: `//[$\r\n]+$`.

In the second case, if there are other chars on the line, they form statements. Any statement is ended by a semicolon `;`. So we search the last statement and its corresponding semicolon `.*;(?!.*")`. Then we search the single line comment. Those other chars can be also preprocessor statements. In this case, they are introduced by a sharp `#`.

One important keypoint is that I assume the code passed to the regex is ***a code that compiles***.

#### There is more

Don't forget also to add some other pre-processor directives that may apply in your case. Check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18014883/363573

Comment: Interesting approach. I will check later if it work with real word source code. I see that it does not support case like this

`#define SOME_CONSTANT 3.14 // pi` 

I think it will be easy to add this feature anyway

Comment: One more case

    `self.viewController.title = @"sdfsdfs" //sdfsdfsdf \n
    "sdfsdf";`

But I really like the way you think

Comment: And the funniest one `NSString *myString = @"dsff; //fsdf";`

Comment: @Ossir I have updated my answer with the new cases you have posted. Don't forget to check the demo. If you find new cases, don't hesitate to post them ;)

Comment: Great job! The case with multiline string still does not covered=) And it look like dead end for me. But I think it's the best I can get here, so I will mark it as correct answer soon

Comment: @Ossir I have found a new case. I have changed the regex in consequence. Check the new demo.

Comment: @Alex Look at two last cases to understand the worst scenario
http://regex101.com/r/mR4sG4 Anyway, you are awesome!